# Convex Sub Level Sets

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I need your help in solving the following problem:

Given a convex function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)$, let $c \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and let $L \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a  non empty sublevel set of $f$ such that:

$$ L = \left\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(x) \leq c\right\rbrace$$

How can I prove that $\forall w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\left\| w \right\|_2 = 1$ there exists a real number $a > 0$ such that 
$$ aw \in L$$

Is it even true?

Please advise.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to asking if $L$ 'encircles' the origin. I am sure you can come up with a counterexample in $n=1$.

Comment: Now i see the problem, then how can it be shown for each boundary point $x$ of the convex body represented by $L$, $f(x) = 1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. Let $f(x)=\sum_i (x_i-1)^2$, and $c=0$. Unless $w$ is such that $w_i=w_j$ for all $j$, $aw$ doesn't go through $L=\{1,1,\dots,1\}$.